# Why are the rendered icons not responding to changes in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to effect the very basic functionality of toggling the password input of a form. Quite simply, I'd like for the user to hide or show the password when entering it.

I'm working with React, with Semantic UI React being the CSS framework. This is a fairly straightforward task, yet I'm having trouble with the icon element not reacting to changes in state. To be precise, the corresponding CSS class for the icon changes from `eye` to `eye slash` as expected. However, the rendered icon does not react to this change in state, and remains the same i.e eye rather than slashed eye. Weirdly enough, the `type` attribute of this input field changes from `text` to `password`, and renders the correct input form (i.e. hidden or displayed password). So, what gives?

Below is the Component's code snippet. I've also included an image of the rendered form with the relevant fields filled.

**Change Password Form**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, Icon, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const styles = {
  //...
};

class PasswordField extends Component {
  state = {
    showPassword: false,
  };

  onTogglePassword = () =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showPassword: !prevState.showPassword,
    }));

  render() {
    const { showPassword } = this.state;
    const { name, value, label, onChange } = this.props;

    return (
      <Form.Field style={styles.formField}>
        <label style={styles.label}>{label}</label>
        <Input
          style={styles.input}
          type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          icon={
            <Icon
              name={showPassword ? 'eye slash' : 'eye'}
              link
              onClick={this.onTogglePassword}
            />
          }
        />
      </Form.Field>
    );
  }
}

PasswordField.propTypes = {
    //...
}

export default PasswordField;
```

**Rendered Form's Image**

[image]

Comment: just pasted your code. Works out of the box. https://codesandbox.io/s/jjq56pyp5w

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati Well, this is rather bizarre. For some twisted reason, it wont work for me.

Comment: I would suggest trying some other icon then, like eye slash outline

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @LazarNikolic Sorry for the rather late response. I still haven't found a solution to it. Weirdly enough, the same thing happens with Vue.js on my local machine but works on CodeSandBox. Figures!

Comment: Have you tried eye slash outline icon?

Comment: @LazarNikolic Yes, I did. Unfortunately, I got the same result i.e. no change.

Answer (score 1):

They actually response to state changes, the problem is with the slash eye Icon!

You can test by using a different icon name, instead of  *eye slash* and It should work. Example:

```
name={showPassword ? 'chevron circle down' : 'eye'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For some reason they dont render correctly. I fixed it by using `hide` and `unhide`. They are the same icons with different names.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
 i.icon.eye.slash.outline:before { content: "\f070"; }
```

into semantic.min.css and problem is solved.